# What is the subequations counter named?

Tags: counters, subequations

If I want to change the equation numbering I can use

```
\addtocounter{equation}{n}.
```

How do I change the subequation numbering? E.g. if I want to label a subequation by 1.7?

Comment: The `subequations` environment actually uses the `equation` counter, so you'd need  `\setcounter{equation}{7}`. The parent equation number is temporarily stored in the `parentequation` counter.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Can you write up an answer to this question (with an example)?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `align` as an example here. You just have to use `\setcounter` before `subequations` environment to change the parent equation number. Using setcounter inside `subequations` environment will change the child equation/subequation number.

```
\setcounter{equation}{parent_equation_number}
\begin{subequations}
\setcounter{equation}{child_equation_number}
\begin{align}
<You equations go there>
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Hope, this helped!